# $firebaseArray losing functions after saving a child element

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am trying to implement a list-details view. The list is generated with `$firebaseArray(ref)`. When an item on the list is clicked, the list controller uses `list.$getRecord(item.$id)` to get the particular record. Puts it in a global service(just and empty object with set and get) and in my detail controller i assign that service(already set to the selected item) to a scope variable in the detail controller and display it.

The information in the detail view is editable. and when it is editted, a save button appears which when clicked saves the edit using this code

```
item = editItem; //editItem contains the new changes made on the detail page 
list.$save(item).then(function(ref){
    //ref.key() === item.$id; // 
    console.log("Your Edit has been saved');
  });
```

This works. The edits are reflected on the remote firebase data.

But the problem occurs when i navigate back to the list view and try to click another item. It gets an error which says `list.$getRecord()` is not a function. Now this error doesn't occur when you don't save an edit on the details view.

I printed out the list array before and after i save and i realised this

**List array before an item is saved (contains AngularFire methods)**
[image: List array before an item is saved]

**List array after an item is saved (no longer contains AngularFire methods)**
[image: List array after an item is saved]

I have no idea why $firebaseArray is reacting this way. Is there something i am missing? is this a normal behaviour? 
PS: i am using ionic and angularFire.

I can post more code if neccesary

**EDIT**
Here is an abstraction of the code

List.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item href="#/lead/info"  ng-click="vm.selectItem(l.$id)" ng-repeat="l in vm.list" >
      <h3>{{l.firstName}} {{l.lastName}}</h3>
      <h4 class="">
        <p>{{l.topic}}</p>
      </h4>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

list.js (controller function)

```
function ListCtrl(selectedItem, $firebaseArray) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;

    vm.list= {};
    vm.selectItem = selectItem;
    loadList(); //Loads the List array

function loadList() {

  var fireList = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/list");
  var r = $firebaseArray(fireList);

  r.$loaded(function () {
    vm.list = r;
  });

  console.log(vm.list); //Outputs the first image(above). But after an item edit and i go back, outputs the second image(above)
}

    function selectItem(index) {
      var sItem = vm.list.$getRecord(index);

      selectedItem.setList(vm.list);
      selectedItem.setItem(sItem);
    }
}
```

The `selectedItem` service is simple. i use it to set a single object or array of objects

```
function selectedItem() {
    var sItem = {};
    var List = {};

    return {
        getItem: function () {
            return sItem;
        },
        setItem: function (authObject) {
            sItem = authObject;
        },
        getList: function(){
          return List;
        },
        setList: function(al){
          List = al;
        }
    };
  };
```

The detail view controller is ass so:

item.js(controller function)

```
function ItemCtrl(selectedItem, $scope, $firebaseObject) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem.getItem();
    $scope.listArray = selectedItem.getList();
    //vm.item = $scope.selectedItem;

 function saveEdit() {

      var t = $scope.selectedItem;

      $scope.listArray.$save(t).then(function(ref){
        //console.log(ref);
      });     
    }
  };
```

**UPDATE**

After serious cross checking throughout my code i realised the issue is not from AngularFiire array. Even the workaround i did with the `r.$watch` and `r.$loaded` was unnecessary. the need for the work around was cause by another part of my code i didnt think was relevant.
I apologise for the mistake. I'd be deleting this question and a related one soon

Comment: Yeah, first, it's listView.$getRecord(). So listView.getRecord() is not a funciton would be correct. Also, we'll need an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be any help with a complex issue like unintended mutation of instances.

Comment: Show some more code.

Comment: @kato that was a typo. i've eddited the question to include some code

Comment: @chrillewoodz i've eddited the question to include some code

Comment: Create a real repro in jsfiddle, et al, and we'll know why this is happening; this is just disjointed snips and the the devil is in the details. It's unclear why all the vm.list = {}; $loaded() stuff is even necessary (hint: it's not). Getting rid of that would be the first step to a real solution. You should only need one declaration of your list, not a bunch of wrappers on wrappers and three to five assignments of the same variable. The whole point of AngularFire is to take care of the loading and binding. You've re-implemented half the lib here trying to handle the loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a watcher to reload the data:

```
var fireList = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/list");
var r = $firebaseArray(fireList);

r.$watch(function() {
  r.$loaded(function () {
    vm.list = r;
  });
});
```

This is a common way of dealing with updates in an easy way, might solve your problem.

Comment: @RaymondAtivie I really don't know myself, sorry. But now you know how to avoid this bug, which is the whole point :) I'd appreciate if you accept my answer :)

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, honestly. Great workaround though.